# How would I remove an item from an array with mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'd like to atomically remove an item from an array. I was looking at using findAndModify but I'm not sure how that would work. Any direction on how to atomically remove an item from an array in a doc would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`$pull`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/pull/) operator in an `update` or `findAndModify` for that:

```
db.collection.update({_id: id}, {$pull: {foo: 'bar'}});
```

This would remove the `'bar'` element from the `foo` array field of the document matching `{_id: id}`.